# Usage of partial application in Q#

Tags: programming, q#

I am working with multiple operations and used partial application in different cases in Q#. I have 2 questions :

- Can a partial applicated operation be passed as an argument ?
- Lets say you have an operation with 3 parameters. Can you first fill one argument, store it, fill another argument, store it, and then finally call the operation by filling the last argument ?

Of course, I you need clarifications, I will comment and edit appropriately. Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a partial applicated operation be passed as an argument ?

Yes.

For example, let's say you want to pass an argument of type `(Qubit => Unit)` (an operation applied to a single qubit, say, a gate), and you want to get it by using `Ry` gate with a fixed rotation angle parameter. The signature of `Ry` operation is `operation Ry (theta : Double, qubit : Qubit) : Unit`, so its type is `((Double, Qubit) => Unit)`. If you use partial application to define a new operation

```
let RyHalfPi = Ry(PI() / 2.0, _);
```

the signature of the new operation will be `(Qubit => Unit)` (since you already defined the first parameter), and it will behave as an operation that takes a single qubit parameter for all purposes, including passing it as an argument.

> Can you first fill one argument, store it, fill another argument, store it, and then finally call the operation by filling the last argument ?

Yes, in exactly the same way as in the first case!

If, for example, you want to use [`R1Frac`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.r1frac) gate with signature `(Int, Int, Qubit) : Unit`, you can first fill in the numerator:

```
let R1Frac10 = R1Frac(10, _, _);
```

to get operation with signature `(Int, Qubit) : Unit`, and then fill in the power to get a single-qubit gate:

```
for (power in 0 .. 1 << 10) {
    let R1Frac10Power = R1Frac10 (power, _);
    // ...
}
```

You can also fill in parameters out of order (not necessarily left to right like I did in the example), following the same principle: you'll get an operation which takes all leftover (unsupplied) arguments in the order in which they are left.

- You can check the testing harnesses of the [Quantum Katas](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/) for more examples - they use partial application quite extensively to use unified testing harness for tasks with slightly different operation signatures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I find this function very powerful, I just think a couple of sentences should be added to the docs so that people don't have to search for this question.

Comment: @Jonathcraft If I may ask to help us make diagnostics more actionable: are you working within an IDE (VS or VS Code, with the QDK extension installed), or are you working in a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: I am working on VS code with the QKD extension and a python host file

Comment: @Jonathcraft Cool. You should soon get more IntelliSense information (if your extension updates automatically) that will make it easier to spot these things right away.